# replacing elements in a multi-dimensional array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a multidimentional array in ruby, like so: `[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]` and I want to remove spaces in every second object of each array with this function `.gsub!(/\s+/, "")`. So it is basically like doing: `[[a, b.gsub!(/\s+/, ""), c], [d, e.gsub!(/\s+/, ""), f], [g, h.gsub!(/\s+/, ""), i]]`

I am a little bit confused, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

Inplace:

```
arr.each { |a| a[1].delete! ' ' }
```

Immutable:

```
arr.dup.each { |a| a[1].delete! ' ' }
```

Comment: Since the poster explicitly asks to use the whitespace character class, I don't think it's safe to assume they're only replacing space characters.

Comment: See my reply to @Drenmi in my answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa - meant that if you are want to do immutable, i.e. create a new object, map does the same thing.

Comment: @Austio there are tons of methods on `Enumerable` that are immutable. That fact does not make them doing the same thing as `.dup.each`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland the question is definitely not about `gsub`, but about _doing operations on second elements of array items_. That’s why I do not bother to add a comment on “use gsub if...”. I like your solution more than mine, because it lacks this nasty access by hard-coded index.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of `gsub` in connection with my answer, as it only affects the second element, but you could have `a[1].gsub!(/\s+/,'')` if you wanted to remove all whitespace (rather than just spaces) from `a[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [["Now is", "the time for", "all"],
       ["good", "people to come", "to", "the"],
       ["aid of", "their bowling", "team"]]

arr.map { |a,b,*c| [a, b.delete(' '), *c] }
  #=> [["Now is", "thetimefor", "all"],
  #    ["good", "peopletocome", "to", "the"],
  #    ["aid of", "theirbowling", "team"]]
```

To mutate `arr`:

```
arr.map! { |a,b,*c| [a, b.delete(' '), *c] }
```

Comment: Since the poster explicitly asks to use the whitespace character class, I don't think it's safe to assume they're only replacing space characters.

Comment: @Drenmi, actually the OP said, "I want to remove spaces...", but then, as you noted,presents a regex that deletes all whitespace. It was good to mention that, but let's not quibble readers: change `b.delete(' ')` to `b.gsub(/\s+/,'')` if whitespace is to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]

arr.map! do |el|
  el[1].gsub!(/\s+/, "")
  el
end
```

Note: This will mutate your original array, which might be something you don't want.